# How to see information related to network tab in chrome mobile browser

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, logging, mobile

Is there any way to see the network related logs in chrome mobile phone browser?

I have tried and I found that in desktop browser we can view network related information

I want to see how page load time in network tab for chrome mobile browser

Comment: I'm not sure about non-Apple devices, but I know the iPhone/iPad don't allow you to use the Chrome console from the phone (it is possible that pluggin the mobile device into an Apple computer may allow you to access the Chrome developer tools, I know this is how you access the Safari developer tools).

Comment: The same way we can see for the chrome browser as well on android devices by inspecting devices in chrome tab

Comment: Ah, good to know. Also, another option (depending on your scenario) could be to use Wireshark or Fiddler or a similar program on the webserver to view the network traffic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you definitely can. Check out this tutorial:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

It'll allow you to debug your mobile browser from the desktop dev tools.

Comment: hi jeff thanks for the answer. im aware of this remote debugging from desktop. what i wanted to know is how to see the network tab of chrome browser with in the mobile it self. Is that possible if not any plugin will show the details

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible. Is there some particular reason you need to debug on the device itself?

Comment: Im trying to automate the entire process of reading page load timings. I know user agent is a possibility but i want an on device solution

Comment: Seems like the link changed to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is a little late but i still leave my answer here.

***Android***

if your `android` app is using `stetho`, then you can:

1. Connect your device with a usb cable to your PC
2. Navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices`
3. It opens a page which includes the list of your devices
4. Click on the link of your device and it opens `Developer tools` of chrome for you, which includes `console`, and `Network` tabs

---

But, keep in mind that your app must benefit from `stetho`, otherwise you don't see anything.

---

***IOS:***

1. Install [Charlesproxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com)
2. Follow [this](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/) guideline